# aws configuration: Mismatch of Security group IDs and names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

I have the following configuration:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
  name = "allow_ssh"
  vpc_id = "${aws_default_vpc.default.id}"
  description = "Allow ssh connections on port 22"
  ingress {
      from_port = 22
      to_port = 22
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "your-app" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}"]
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.twilio_key.key_name}"
}
```

When I do `terraform apply`, I get this error:

```
* aws_instance.your-app: Error launching instance, possible mismatch of Security Group IDs and Names. See AWS Instance docs here: https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html.

        AWS Error: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
```

What should I do to solve the above error ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to change `id` to `name` for it to work:

```
resource "aws_instance" "twilio-app" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.twilio_key.key_name}"
  security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.name}" ]
}
```

It accepts group name and not the id parameter.

Comment: this resolve my issue, but the document said name or ids:

security_groups - (Optional, EC2-Classic and default VPC only) A list of security group names (EC2-Classic) or IDs (default VPC) to associate with.

Answer (score 6):

I'm Adding another solution here because I encountered the same issue and changing the security group `id` to the `name` didn't solve the problem.

Checking on [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) under the `instance` resource we can see the usage of the `security_groups` argument:

```
security_groups - (Optional, EC2-Classic and default VPC only) A list of security group names (EC2-Classic) or IDs (default VPC) to associate with.
```

Under that we can see the following note:

> NOTE: If you are creating Instances in a VPC, use
>   vpc_security_group_ids instead.

And the description of the `vpc_security_group_ids` argument:

```
vpc_security_group_ids - (Optional, VPC only) A list of security group IDs to associate with.
```

**So for me changing from** `security_groups` **to** `vpc_security_group_ids` **solved the issue**.